# Rss and external feed

Tags: rss, cross-domain, external, feed, dashcode

I want to build a similar app like this:http://community.livejournal.com/ohnotheydidnt/32551171.html
using a livejournal rss feed. Any way of retrieving an external feed ( meaning getting a feed from a different domain that the one your web application-Same origin policy)? I've built a parser, but I would like to use dashcode for simple html building.

Comment: Can't you just read the XML straight out of the external RSS feed?

Answer (score 2):

Across domains, if the data is only available via RSS and you don't have control of the other domain, then your best option is a [server-side proxy](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Cross-Domain_Proxy).

If you have control over the other domain, you can create a page containing a javascript function which uses XmlHttpRequest to pull the RSS and returns the RSS. Then you can use a cross-domain messaging library like [EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/) to call that script.

You also might want to check if the RSS feed's website supports [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) as an alternate format, which would allow you to get the RSS data via javascript. Make sure you trust the site if you do this, though, since the site can execute javascript inside your page!